# Android Stone SDK Integration - Android manifest does not recognize activities anymore

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-manifest

I'm trouble with my App. I'm trying to integrate Stone Android SDK. But, after i import the librarys in the gradle files (root and app) and synchronize, android studio presents an issue.

```
//stone modulos
implementation 'br.com.stone:stone-sdk:3.8.2'


maven { url "https://packagecloud.io/stone/sdk-android/maven2" }
        maven { url "https://packagecloud.io/stone/sdk-android-snapshot/maven2" }
        maven { url "https://packagecloud.io/stone/sdk-android-internal/maven2" }
```

Android studio says that AndroidManifest.xml file does not recognize the activities anymore. Even for me, all the activities are present there. Let me try to explain better.

[image]

Even i change the configs from default 'lauch: default activity' to a specified activity, i got a warning Warning: The activity 'WelcomeActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

But it's declared in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

And my layout files are like this
[image]

What could be happening?